# Unicode Explanation Required

Tags: unicode

Can someone explain what this means?

> Unicode defines a codespace of 1,114,112 code points in the range 0<sub>hex</sub> to 10FFFF<sub>hex</sub>.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A code point or code position is any of the numerical values that make up the codespace.

As per the Wikipedia entry on [Code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point):

> The notion of a code point is used for abstraction, to distinguish both:
>
> - the number from an encoding as a sequence of bits, and
> - the abstract character from a particular graphical representation (glyph).
>
> This is because one may wish to make these distinctions:
>
> - encode a particular code space in different ways, or
> - display a character via different glyphs.

So Unicode defines space for over a million distinct glyphs, which are accessed in the hex range from 0 to 10FFFF. You may be familiar with Extended ASCII which comprises 256 code points in the range 0hex to FFhex.

Answer (score 9):

The value of 0x10FFFF is 1,114,111. Between 0x000000 and 0x10FFFF, you have 1,114,112 numerical values. In Unicode, every character is represented by a number in the range 0 through 1,114,111. Software then interprets this numerical value to render the character on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The `codespace` is an abstract layer between the glyphs (User Interface level) and the (byte-)encoding. Every character defined in Unicode has its own `code point`, and there 1,114,112 possible code points (not all are used).

For example, the euro sign is always code point U+20AC.
Depending on the selected encoding it may be encoded as `+IKw-` (UTF-7), `E2 82 AC`<sub>hex</sub> (UTF-8), `20 AC`<sub>hex</sub> (UTF-16) OR `00 00 20 AC`<sub>hex</sub> (UTF-32).

Comment: it would be nice (+1) if you could include an example to show how a character looks at the interface level along with its unicode equivalent along with how it would look in its byte-encoding